# Docusign EventNotification CSRF Protection

Tags: spring, docusignapi, csrf

I'm trying to use the Docusign REST API (Java specific) to to add docusign functionality to my application. I'm adding in the com.docusign.esign.model.EventNotification to my EnvelopeDefinition so that I can get notifications from docusign - I want to know when someone signs/views a document so that I can update my own internal data and notify the next people in the chain that they should sign a document.

The problem is with Spring Security's CSRF protection. EventNotifications are sent to my server, but they are blocked due to 403 errors.

Everything else works - envelopes are created, I can do embedded signing, I can manually poll docusign for envelope/recipient statuses, etc. And I do know that the callbacks are coming back. If I disable CSRF protection in my Spring configuration, then the eventnotifications hit my configured callback URL and process as intended. If I turn on CSRF protection, my server's logs show me 403 errors for the callback URLs.

Obviously I don't want to disable CSRF protection. And it doesn't seem to make sense to selectively disable CSRF protection specifically for that listener URL. But I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm digging through the documentation, and I'm not seeing anything that gives me a hint as to how I can handle CSRF for a callback from docusign.

Is there a different way I should be approaching my configuration? Maybe it does make sense to disable CSRF for this callback, seeing as I absolutely expect it to come from some external source. But then how do I secure it? Should I disable CSRF for this particular event and implement a different security measure?

I'm using Spring 4.3.8, Docusign API 3.1.0, and Struts 2.3.37.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: I recommend that you set up a separate Spring server (listener) that will receive the event notifications. There's no way for webhook notifications to pass the nounce used in a standard GET/POST CSRF defense since there's no GET.

### Details

The typical GET (a form) followed by POST (the form) flow guards against a CSRF attack by including a nounce value when the form is sent to the browser and checking that the same value is provided in a POST.

With webhook notifications (such as DocuSign's Connect / eventNotification system), the nounce pattern for stopping CSRF attacks won't work since your application is not and cannot anticipate when notifications will be POSTed to your app via the webhook. (No form is sent to the webhook software by your app.)

This issue is common to all webhook implementations, not specific to DocuSign.

Instead, to guard against someone sending a forged webhook notification message, different techniques are used. These days, a common and secure technique is to include an HMAC digital signature with the notification. The HMAC cryptographically guarantees both that the message was sent by the authorized sender and that it wasn't altered during transmission.

Your app should use the anti-CSRF guard for its GET/POST flows. If you can't disable the CSRF check for just the notification endpoints on your app, I'd suggest two servers, one will just receive the webhook event notifications.